# Numbered lists not matching section numbers in Word

Tags: microsoft-word

I'm going nuts here.

I have heading 1's in my Word document that all number correctly and populate the contents.

But whenever I place a numbered list in say the section 3 - I cannot for the life of me get it to start at 3.1, 3.2 etc. It ALWAYS starts either back at 1 or continued from another list in a previous section.

Any help would be great as I have invested so much time in this now.

Comment: Are you setting them as Heading 2 or setting the outline level as one below whatever the Heading 1 lines are set to (Level 2)? Try switching to Outline View to see what's going on with the levels. They should show up in a nested format.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't really seem to tell me any more then I could already see

I can't seem to find any decent tutorial on including a chapter number

https://www.dropbox.com/s/d5wzsev2bjxcudz/Screenshot%202019-12-03%20at%2016.20.57.png?dl=0

Comment: It would be helpful to know how all this is formatted, otherwise we are just guessing

Comment: So I have it working now except now all the h2's show up in my TOC!?

I will attach screen shots of the setup